# How to target a property of an object returned by an api that is the format "XYZ-ABC"?

Tags: node.js, pokeapi

I am trying to fetch an img returned by the api(pokeapi.co) which is a property of an object 'official-artwork'. I am getting a following error:

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: artwork is not defined
```

I am not sure how to fetch results out of objects named like that or if its even possible to retrieve info out of these objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using `data.official-artwork` (dot notation) to retrieve the `official-artwork` property from data. Simply replace by `data["official-artwork"]` (bracket notation)

You can read more about property accessors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Right! Thank you, I'll keep that in mind from now on